# How can I use EntityManager in my service class?

Tags: php, symfony

I am doing app where I need register user.

> RegisterController

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
 {
   public function indexAction(Request $request){        
   }

   public function registerUserAction(Request $request) {
    $newUser = new Register();
    $newUser = $newUser->addNewUser($username, $password);
   }
 }
```

> Service Register

```
class Register
 {
   public function addNewUser($username, $password) {
    if(self::validateUsername($username) && self::validatePassword($password)) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }
   }
}
```

> config/services.yaml
>   services:

```
_defaults:
    autowire: true     
    autoconfigure: true 
    public: false     
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Of course I can't access doctrine and entity manager in Register and I don't know how I can do this. 
Please don't post symfony documentation about service containers, I read it all and don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by injecting the entity manager into your Register service:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Register
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    public function addNewUser($username,$password)
    {
        $user = new User($username,$password);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Next, we take advantage of a somewhat unusual Symfony feature sometimes known as controller action injection:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\Register;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RegisterController
{
    public function registerUserAction(Request $request, Register $register)
    {
        $newUser = $register->addNewUser($username, $password);
        return new Response('Register Userx');
    }
}
```

And that is it.  Symfony autowire takes care of connecting things up.  Hopefully, this will make some of the service container documentation more understandable.

Comment: I think I did dis previously, but now did again. My classes looks exactly as you wrote but I am getting error 'Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Service\Register::__construct(), 0 passed in src/Controller/RegisterController.php on line 21 and exactly 1 expected' @Cerad

Comment: Well, I did this. Thank you very much. @Cerad

Comment: Is it working now?  The too few arguments error message indicates you are doing new Register() somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add it in other methods.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You might want to go ahead and accept the answer just so other folks will know it helped.  And of course we both get reps.